# "We asked because of what she laughed" - why is the sentence wrong?

Tags: content-clauses

> We asked because of what she laughed.

This sentence is supposed to be grammatically wrong. Why is it so? What is the correct version?

Comment: Do you know what's wrong with it? There's at least two options.

Comment: "We asked because of what she laughed AT" would make sense.

Comment: It would be very unusual, but I can see a way this sentence would be correct. In fiction, laughed can be used to mean *spoke words with a laughing voice* then she could have laughed a comment. The comment which she laughed might then prompt others to ask a question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laughing does not typically report speech.

> *She laughed a good idea.
>   ?She laughed hello.
>   She said hello.

Since in this case, *what* stands for an argument to *laugh*, which is at best questionable.

You can repair this by changing either the verb, or *what*:

- We asked because of **why/when** she laughed.
- We asked because of what she **said**.

There are many more possibilities, but those two options probably change the sentence the *least*.

Comment: +1 It could also be intended to represent *We asked **why** she laughed* or *We asked **what** she was laughing about*.

Comment: yeah, there's many possibilities... let me address that.

Comment: And what about this version: We asked from what reason she laughed.

Comment: @bart that wouldn't work in most contexts. It's at least archaic, if not outright ungrammatical.

Comment: @bart-leby You could say *We asked **for** what reason she laughed*, but this should be avoided because the collocation *ask for* usually means *request*.

Comment: You could also swap over the verbs.  "We laughed because of what she asked."

Comment: Yep. There are a million changes you could make to make the sentence grammatical. There's no good reason to try to mention just some of them, unless it's particularly likely to occur for some reason.

Comment: One thing to note is that, although you're completely right that laughing doesn't typically report speech, it certainly can. For example "He laughed that the poor would have to pay for the gains of the rich." Alternatively, "'You can't build a city in a day,' she laughed." Both seem totally felicitous.

Comment: @Dennis yes, but I would argue that in those cases, we're attributing laughter to the act of speech, and therefore, if you were to ask about it, you wouldn't say _what did they laugh?_, but rather, _what did they say?_

Comment: @jimsug Yes, _what did they laugh?_ certainly seems tortured. Rather, laughing here is serving to convey that something was said in a sort of sneering way ("sneering" might be too harsh, but something along those lines). So, it's more of a mode of utterance issue, the laughing gives the assertion an extra flavor to it -- something like mocking.

Answer (score 12):

"Because of what" is not something you say often in English when "what" is a question.  (It is often used when "what" refers to something: "I had to apologize because of what he did" - but it is not used to ask something, as in the original sentence.)

When asking a question, often you would use "why" instead

> We asked why she laughed.

or more likely,

> We asked why she was laughing.

Also, you don't laugh *because of* something, you laugh *at* it or *about* it.  So

> We asked what she was laughing at.
>
> We asked what she was laughing about.

although as others have pointed out, you could laugh *because of* being tickled or inhaling laughing gas or whatever.

Comment: While it's not common to laugh _because_ of something, it is possible. Being tickled often causes people to involuntarily laugh.

Comment: "Because of what" is fine in other phrases - "Because of what she said", "Because of what she ate", "Because of what she did" etc. I think the main differences is those are transitive verbs.

Comment: I completely agree with bdsl and disagree with this answer. "Because of what" is quite common. "The girl yelled at the bully **because of what** he had done to her sister." For this particular case, there's not a more natural way to say it.

Comment: Also, laughing because is perfectly fine. "When he said ‘your hair looks stupid’, I laughed because he had toilet paper stuck to his shoe, which looked far more ridiculous."

Comment: Yeah, saying that _because of what_ is not often used is not really right. _Because of what happened_, _because of what they saw_, _because of what was broken_, _because of what_... I could find more examples, but this answer _pretty much_ starts with an incorrect premise.

Comment: ErikE: you laughed "because he had toilet paper stuck to his shoe", fine, but not "because OF he had toilet paper stuck to his shoe".  You don't laugh "because of" something, although as with any action, you can laugh because...

Answer (score 2):

Grammar, dimly remembered from schooldays ...

In English, the fundamental structure of a grammatically correct sentence is [subject] [verb] [object]. Subject and verb are not optional, but some *intransitive* verbs do not accept an object. In "I took a biscuit", the subject is "I", the verb is "took" and the object (the thing that the verb is referring to) is "a biscuit". "Laughed" is intransitive. You can't laugh anything, you just laugh. If you laugh and [then] say something, that's exactly how you write it. 'She laughed, and said "Never!".'

Subject and object are frequently phrases rather than single words. In my first sentence above, "the fundamental structure of a grammatically correct sentence" is the subject.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it's very rare to use the verb laugh *transitively*. It is possible for laugh to be used transitively, but it's usually (maybe even exclusively) used that way to qualify the laugh itself.

E.g., (from [englishpractice.com](http://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/intransitive-verbs-transitive-verbs/))

- We **fought** a good **fight**
- We **laughed** such a hearty **laugh** that we fell out of our seats.

This might be a stretch, but I'm trying to play with it a bit by composing something that might allow it to work in a certain context:

> She laughed a laugh that was completely ridiculous; she laughed what was the loudest laugh we'd ever heard. We wondered, "Can this really be?" because what she laughed seemed impossible. We asked because of what she laughed.

Comment: May be my misunderstanding stemms from the fact that I consider "why" and "because of what" to be synonyms which is probably not so. I supposed that "Why are you laughing"? = "Because of what are you laughing"?

Comment: 'because of what' is not interrogative but explicative.

Comment: @bart-leby: it seems you have correctly identified your issue; "why" and "because of what" are not equivalent.  Both why and what indicate a question, "because of x" indicates an answer.  Because of what is neither a question nor an answer.  So, you could say "We asked why she laughed" or "We asked what caused her to laugh".  It can sorta be made to work but would need a lot more context (and punctuation).  "We asked, because she laughed, what was so funny about the letter she was reading". I'm not sure it can be made to work with the "what" included.

Answer (score 0):

Although other answers have pointed out that laughter does not convey speech, this is not necessarily true.

> "You look like little red riding hood," he laughed.

[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=gf89AQvdnBsC&pg=PA115&dq=%22he%20laughed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCGoVChMIk7PK4bqOyAIVhjc-Ch21WAoJ#v=onepage&q=%22he%20laughed%22&f=false)

> "I like to be comfortable", he laughed.

[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=jtOz61XEuMMC&pg=PA11&dq=%22he%20laughed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CE8Q6AEwCTgKahUKEwiu8sLnu47IAhWBQD4KHZnYBiU#v=onepage&q=%22he%20laughed%22&f=false)

> "Yes, yes," he laughed, "I've been through the mill."

[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=pGFFaJR-2HIC&pg=PT113&dq=%22he%20laughed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBTgeahUKEwieo_DSvI7IAhVBbD4KHRCoD4c#v=onepage&q=%22he%20laughed%22&f=false)

> "Hello, sweet ladies," he laughed in a fruity, musical voice.

[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=_nTgBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT73&dq=%22he%20laughed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEAQ6AEwBjh4ahUKEwjdy4Czvo7IAhXCPD4KHeBgAPc#v=onepage&q=%22he%20laughed%22&f=false)

So the sentence is not technically ungrammatical.

Ordinarily the distinction is made between speaking and laughing, and certainly it's hard to speak intelligibly while laughing, so the sentence sounds quite odd.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers assume you mean "We asked [a question] because of [what she laughed]".

However, I think what you actually mean is simply "We asked her **why** she laughed".

**Correct alternatives**

The most common ways to say this would be:

- We asked [her] why she laughed.
- We asked what she was laughing about.

These would also be correct:

- We asked what the cause of her laughter was.
- We asked her what caused her to laugh.
- We asked her the reason for her laughter.
- We asked for what reason she laughed.

I think this one is correct but sounds awkward:

- We asked her what she laughed because of.

**Problems with "We asked because of what she laughed":**

1. The sentence structure "We <verb> because of <...>" almost always gives the cause <...> for an action. E.g. "We jumped because of a loud noise." All the other answers (so far) have interpreted your sentence like this.
2. "Because of what" is *occasionally* used instead of "why" for emphasis, e.g. "You're late, because of what?" However, it is never placed before the action: "Because of what, you're late?" does not make sense.